# How to convert mhtml to png?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I make chrome extension.

I use chrome API method "chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML"
that I can get callback function with mhtml data as blob.

so I want to convert the blob to png type file and download it.

Actually, by the code below I can download png file but the file is broken , if I am about to open it,
The message appeared "The file is not supported".

How can I get a valid png file from mthml data?

Thanks.

example code

event.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(
    function (port) {
        port.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
            submitMHTML(request.id);
        });
    });

function submitMHTML(id) {
    chrome.tabs.query(
        {active:true, lastFocusedWindow: true},
        function (array_of_Tabs) {
            if (array_of_Tabs.length > 0) {
                var tab = array_of_Tabs[0];
                savePage(tab.id);
            }
        }
    )
}
function savePage(tabId) {
    chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML(
        { tabId: tabId }, function (blob) {

            var modifyBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: 'image/png' });
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(modifyBlob);

            //chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(downloadListener);
    

            // Optional: chrome.tabs.remove(tabId); // to close the tab
            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: url,
                filename: 'whatever/aaa.png'
            });
        }
    );
}

function downloadListener(downloadItem, suggest) {
    suggest({ filename: 'whatever/Whatever.png' });
    chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.removeListener(downloadListener);
}
```

popup.js

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true },function(tabs){
        var port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "test" });
        port.postMessage({nanikatameshi:"nanikatameshi1"});
        port.onMessage.addListener({ id: tabs[0].id }, {message: "message1"}, 
             function (item) {
                if (!item) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    return;
                }
        });
    });
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Capture!!</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "pageCaptureExtension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [ "event.js" ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "pageCapture",
        "declarativeContent",
        "downloads"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "" ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.min.js",
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "API_SAMPLE",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: Use chrome.tabCapture API instead, then use DOM canvas to extract a screenshot. I didn't do it so look for examples yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I try it!!